# Identify when a value matches another and replace with another specified value R

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data:

```
ID <- c(7,7,7,3,3,4,4,4,10,10,5)
t <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3)
z <- c(NA,NA,NA,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,10)
dt <- data.table(ID,t,z)

    ID  t  z
 1:  7 NA NA
 2:  7 NA NA
 3:  7 NA NA
 4:  3  1  7
 5:  3 NA NA
 6:  4 NA NA
 7:  4 NA NA
 8:  4 NA NA
 9: 10  2  4
10: 10 NA NA
11:  5  3 10
```

I would like this to happen in this order:

- whenever 7 occurs in ID, it is changed to the value of ID when t=1
- whenever 4 occurs in ID, it is changed to the value of ID when t=2
- whenever 10 occurs in ID, it is changed to the value of ID when t=3

I have tried this but it doesn't work, and I would need to repeat this for t=1, t=2 and t=3:

```
dt[ID[match(ID, z[t == 1L])], ID := ID[t == 1L]]
dt[ID[match(ID, z[t == 2L])], ID := ID[t == 2L]]
dt[ID[match(ID, z[t == 3L])], ID := ID[t == 3L]]
```

Is it possible to correct my code, and then find a simpler way to repeat it from t=1 to t=3 in order?

The desired result looks like this because in ID the 4s have been changed to 10s, and then the 10s have been changed to 5s:

```
    ID  t  z
 1:  3 NA NA
 2:  3 NA NA
 3:  3 NA NA
 4:  3  1  7
 5:  3 NA NA
 6:  5 NA NA
 7:  5 NA NA
 8:  5 NA NA
 9:  5  2  4
10:  5 NA NA
11:  5  3 10
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a `for` loop after creating a dataset by removing the NA rows

```
dt1 <- dt[complete.cases(t,z)]
#Or
#dt1 <- na.omit(dt) 
#loop through the sequence of rows in 'dt1'
#based on the logical index on 'i' for 'ID', assign 'ID' to the corresponding 'ID' in 'dt1'
for(i in seq_len(nrow(dt1))){
  dt[ID %in% dt1$z[i], ID := dt1$ID[i]][]
}

dt
#    ID  t  z
# 1:  3 NA NA
# 2:  3 NA NA
# 3:  3 NA NA
# 4:  3  1  7
# 5:  3 NA NA
# 6:  5 NA NA
# 7:  5 NA NA
# 8:  5 NA NA
# 9:  5  2  4
#10:  5 NA NA
#11:  5  3 10
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever 7 occurs in ID, it is changed to the value of ID when t=1

```
ID[which(ID==7)]=ID[which(t==1)]
```

whenever 4 occurs in ID, it is changed to the value of ID when t=2

```
ID[which(ID==4)]=ID[which(t==2)]
```

whenever 10 occurs in ID, it is changed to the value of ID when t=3

```
ID[which(ID==10)]=ID[which(t==3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to specify the first 'which' argument so that it identifies the values in ID that match the value in z when t=1, t=2 etc? Rather than having to enter ID==7, ID==4 and ID==10?